# AngularJS nested ng-repeats with nested bindings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to make an entirely dynamic angularJS page in such a way that the data-model and header-column-model can be passed in as JSON format and the angular/view can decode everything no matter how many columns, etc.

I have everything (Column Headers, single-Column sorting, multi-Column textbox filtering) working except the data portion where it looks like I want to nest {{bindings}}.

The idea is something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in model | filter:filters | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
    <td ng-repeat="header in headers">{{{{$parent.item}}.{{header.colName}}}}</td>
</tr>
```

So that it would resolve to item.column (which is how this is done normally/statically).

However, there doesn't seem to be any embedding/nesting allowed for the double-squiggle references; aka. the first '{{' matches with the first '}}' automatically.

Is there a [good] way to do this?

Comment: `<td ng-repeat="header in item.headers">{{header.colName}}</td>`

Comment: This does not seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$eval`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in model | filter:filters | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
    <td ng-repeat="header in headers">{{$eval('item.' + header.colName}}</td>
</tr>
```

Here is a plunker showing that concept:
http://plnkr.co/edit/msGuMCCj477jyUAqjChz?p=preview